# WooCommerce intercept notice's data

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce, notice

In WooCommerce, is there a way to intercept notice's data array, particularly its key, after removing an item from the cart and do so in **cart.php** without employing a hook?

[image]

Comment: why without a hook, specifically?

Comment: I need one information from that notice, the value of key of deleted item to be passed to cart.php. Based on that value I then manipuate the way the cart looks like and this is very important to know if last item removed was of partcular ID/key. I wrote some creazy stuff in order to intercept this, and that involves `$GLOBALS`, so now I am thinking I could go with a hook and achieve same result...

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a crazy solution for this.
In my case, and most likely in every case, the string I needed to get a piece from looked like this and the part that interested me was the value of `remove_item`:

```
http://site.local/cart/?remove_item=c995axxxxx52bffyyyyy917f67&_wpnonce=1cddf7f858
```

so what I did:

1. Copied woocommerce/templates/notices/**success.php** in to my child theme.
2. Exploded parts of string based on `=` - `$part1 = explode( '=', $notice['notice'] );`
3. Exploded second chunk of that array based on `&` - `$part2 = explode( '&', $part1[2] );`

`$part2[0]` is the piece of the string I want.
Now `$GLOBALS['my_string']` did the rest.

It's rather chisel and hammer, but works like a charm.

```
    $part1    = explode( '=', $notice['notice'] );
    $part2    = explode( '&', $part1[2] );
    $hashed   = $part2[0];

    $membership_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( MEMBERSHIP_PRODUCT_ID );

    $getRemovedID = $membership_cart_id === $hashed ? true : false;
    $GLOBALS['was_membership_removed_just_now'] = $getRemovedID;
```